# Reverse Geocoding: Add municipality to resultant shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, reverse-geocoding

I have a list of points with Lat & Long coordinates that I've plotted on the map. I used reverse geocoding to attach the corresponding address. The resultant shapefile returns the lat & long fields as well as street address. However, I will need to add the Municipality to make the data more usable. For example, I need to differentiate the same addresses in different cities (i.e. 123 Test St exists in both City A and City B). Basically, I need my output to contain four things: lat, long, address, municipality.

I've looked into the reverse geocde tool, but I can't seem to select the fields I want in the output. Is there a way to add this to my output or do I need to use a different tool to achieve this?

My address points that I'm using for my address locator has the municipality information that I'm looking for.

I'm running ArcGIS 10.1 (I have the basic license).

Answer (score 1):

The fields for the output of the `Reverse Geocode` tool are dependent on the address locator you use. The address locators, when used to geocode, require certain fields, such as number, street, city, or state. When `Reverse Geocoding`, your output will contain the fields that the address locator requires as input to geocode. If municipality isn't one of them, you won't get municipality as an output of `Reverse Geocode`.

When using Geocode Addresses:
[image]

Reverse Geocode returns Address Locator input fields:
[image]

To get a certain output field, you'll need to find or construct an address locator with the desired field, or find a polygon feature class of the municipalities and perform a `spatial join` on the feature class output of your `Reverse Geocode`.